# Run file.tex from terminal - Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, windows, command-line

I'd like to open a file.tex (with spaces like: "Interpretazione della relazione π_i maggiore di Π_s.tex") from terminal. I tried to open the terminal in the folder where there is the file.tex and I wrote the command:

```
pdflatex Interpretazione della relazione π_i maggiore di Π_s.tex
```

and the output is:

```
...
! I can't find file 'Interpretazione'.
...
```

How can I run it from terminal? I'm using Texmaker on Windown 10.

Comment: You should write each space as `\ `, so with a slash in front. If you start typing `pdflatex Interpr` for example and then press the `Tab` key then Windows will automatically insert the file name in the correct format.

Comment: Hello @Marijn thank you very much for your clarification. It works very well

Comment: @Marijn repost as an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess it is not really a LaTeX question, it's more about how to use the Windows command prompt, maybe I'll vote to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about LaTeX but instead about how to use the Windows command prompt.

Comment: sort of marginal but arguably a question about how to pass spaces to tex, even if the answer is actually true for any command on each platform. But not answering is also reasonable:-) @Marijn